# How do i reposition the Nav of my wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im a newbie, working on a wordpress website http:// www.smope.net, i'll love to put the "about us" menu directly under the yellow smile in the logo.

I tried to use google chrome's inspector to locate the css ID and  file, but i have not had any success in aligning the nav menu slightly to the right

I'll appreciate your help

Comment: So you're looking to change the order of your items ?

Comment: hello @axel thanks for finding time to reply me, i just want to move the navigation a little to the right, so that the about-us menu can be centered directly under the yellow smiles in the logo

Comment: I would not move the menu if i was You. From a designer view, the menu would not be centered anymore. I would just change the order of your items in your WP-Menu, Like this : In you Wp Admin, go to Appearance -> Menus, than you can drag and drop your items to reorder them.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following properties to `.main-navigation ul` to make it look like this:

You can use `margin-left` in CSS to define the distance between two objects horizontally.

```
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 230px;
    text-align: center;
}
```